# Not able to generate java stubs from .wsdl files using jaxb-runtime 4.0.3 and maven-jaxb2-plugin 0.15.3

Tags: jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am using Java 17. It works fine if I use jaxb-runtime 2.3.3 and maven-jaxb2-plugin 0.14.0. I need to upgrade to jaxb-runtime 4.0.3. In .xjb I have replaced all javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement by jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement and all http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb by http://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb. But getting the following error:

```
Error injecting: org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2.XJC2Mojo java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener.
```

My pom.xml is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.skf.messaging</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-messaging-ws-objects</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>common-messaging-ws-objects</name>
    <description>common-messaging-ws-objects</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
        <sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>./target/dependency-check-report.html</sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>
        <sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>./target/dependency-check-report.json</sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>wcl</id>
            <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/skforg/WCL-2020/_packaging/wcl/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>7.4.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <formats>
                            <format>xml</format>
                            <format>html</format>
                            <format>json</format>
                        </formats>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.15.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The maven plugin has been updated to support jakarta namespace (jaxb api 3 and 4).

You can follow up the [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) to help you get the project configuration updated to work with the v4 version of the jaxb-tools.

Feel free to create a github issue if needed, we'd be happy to help you more to make it work (or provide feedback if migration guide is incomplete / not obvious so we can get it updated to help other users).

Regards